# how to export the configuration for a specific module

Tags: magento2, importexport

good morning everyone , i have a configuration was set in the Magento 2 backend for a specific module , i have search on the web on it , and i have find that there is a command to do it :

```
bin/magento app:config:dump {config-types}

or 

bin/magento app:config:dump scopes themes ==> for themes
```

ref ==> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-config-mgmt-export.html

> but my question is how to export just the configuration for just a specific module ?

Comment: check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105634/how-to-export-import-configs-in-magento

Comment: https://github.com/semaio/Magento2-ConfigImportExport